# How do I bind variables to arbitrary elements of an svg included by {@html svg}?

Tags: svg, svelte, svelte-component

I'm including a dynamically generated SVG file into a component using `{@html svg}`. I need to do some magic. The SVG has embedded scripts, but they're not triggering, and I don't think they'd work anyway (they use `getElementById`).

So if I can just bind variables to arbitrary elements in the included SVG, then I could put scripts in place to do what needs to be done. Is there a way for me to bind variables to arbitrary elements in a pregenerated, dynamic SVG being included by `{@html svg}`? I know I can't do things like `getElementById`, but I also can't use `bind:this`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying the DOM is usually not necessary since there are better alternative ways with Svelte. But in case the elements are created via `{@hmtl}` I think there's no other way to get a reference to them. They are accessible inside the `onMount` callback, when the component has been mounted to the DOM.

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    onMount(() => {
        const rect = document.getElementById('rect')
        console.log(rect)
    })

    const svg = '<svg viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect id="rect" width="100" height="100" /></svg>'
</script>

{@html svg}
```